# How can I initialize K means clustering on a data matrix with 569 rows (samples), and 30 columns (features)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

I'm having trouble understanding how to begin my solution. I have a matrix with 569 rows, each representing a single sample of my data, and 30 columns representing the features of each sample. My intuition is to plot each individual row, and see what the clusters (if any) look like, but I can't figure out how to do more than 2 rows on a single scatter plot.

I've spent several hours looking through tutorials, but have not been able to understand how to apply it to my data. I know a scatter plot takes 2 vectors as a parameter, so how could I possibly plot all 569 samples to cluster them? Am I missing something fundamental here?

```
 #our_data is a 2-dimensional matrix of size 569 x 30

 plt.scatter(our_data[0,:], our_data[1,:], s = 40)
```

My goal is to start k means clustering on the 569 samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a 30-dimensinal factor space, it is difficult to plot such data in 2D space (i.e. on canvas). In such cases usually apply dimension reduction techniques first. This could help to understand data structure.  You can try to apply,e.g. PCA (principal component analysis) first, e.g.

```
#your_matrix.shape = (569, 30)
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
projected_data = pca.fit_transform(your_matrix)
plt.scatter(projected_data[:,0], projected_data[:, 1]) # This might be very helpful for data structure understanding... 
plt.show()
```

You can also look on other (including non-linear) dimension reduction techniques, such as, e.g. T-sne.

Further you can apply k-means or something else; or apply k-means to projected data.

Comment: Adding to @bubble answer, before applying K means, make sure you scale your each column between a range of 0 to 1 so that your distance is not biased towards any of the column values.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That's a great way to put it. I'm new to this so this is really good guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If by initialize you mean picking the k initial clusters, one of the common ways of doing so is to use K-means++ [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) which was developed in order to avoid poor clusterings.

It essentially entails semi-randomly choosing centers based upon a probability distribution of distances away from a first center that is chosen completely randomly.